# Mysql Connection Pool con Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

Estoy intentando conectarme a una base de datos por medio de una Connection Pool, pero no logro que la conexión se logre.

Cuando utilizaba servlets, me conectaba al datasource generado con Glassfish de la siguiente forma:

```
public Connection makeConnection() throws SQLException{
        Connection con=null;
        try{
            InitialContext ic=new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds=(DataSource)ic.lookup("jdbc/javaAntiguaBurguer");
            con = ds.getConnection();
            
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return con;
    }
```

Entonces traté de replicar el mismo principio en el application.properties de un proyecto Spring Boot, pero no se logra realizar la conexión.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.datasource.url=jdbc/javaAntiguaBurguer
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podria ayudar indicandome, cual es la forma correcta de realizarlo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: MIrate esa respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59292973/how-to-get-jndi-datasource-in-spring-boot-from-ibm-websphere-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear un Datasource por JNDI puede utilizar la siguiente clase:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class JndiDataSourceConfig {

    private static final String JNDI = "jdbc/javaAntiguaBurguer";

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(JNDI);
    }
}
```

y no olvides quitar las propiedades de `spring.datasource` del archivo de configuracion.